# How can I sort out a Raspbian/OSMC scenario?

Tags: raspbian

I have my Raspberry Pi 2 hooked up to my TV monitor. I am very new to using it but want to use it to learn programming on but the feature of using OSMC to playback videos from a flash drive is also very beneficial. I don't need OMSC for anything else just to play back my video files. Is there any way I can set up my raspberry pi 2 to playback video in good quality like OSMC but still be able to boot up into the Raspbian GUI so I can work on learning programming when I'm not watching TV?

Comment: Haver you considered using 2 SD cards?

Comment: I actually did not :P thank you! Feel very stupid for not thinking of that.

Comment: No need to feel stupid some times we over think the problem.

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to do this:

the easiest would be to work with **two SD cards** and **swap them** every time you change your need.

sure if this happens several times a day this could become annoying, and so there is another option...

---

with a little bit extra work you can use [BerryBoot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) to **create a multiboot** system with [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/) and [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/)/[OpenELEC](http://openelec.tv/). BerryBoot is something like a bootloader, OS installer and OS manager.

and if changing the OS without changing the SD card is also too slow/annoying for you...

---

with a little bit more extra work (since OSMC is based on Debian) you can **access the terminal** (while shutting down OSMC) and (after installing) **start nearly every desktop environment** from the [Debian Repositories](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages).

...or **work without any DE** and **just the Terminal**.

---

**BUT** if you really just want to play a video you can for example also **use [`omxplayer`](http://omxplayer.sconde.net/)** (the player used/created by [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/)) or some other player within Raspbian! maybe you have to install it (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y omxplayer`) first.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel like a moron for not thinking of the two SD card scenario. Berryboot sounds exactly like what I was after as well. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: if it was the answer you are looking for, mark it as answered!